# extract text from pdf by using php

Tags: php, pdf, output, space

I am writing an web app to extract text coentent from pdf. What i am using is class.pdf2text.php. Follow the instruction, the syntax i used is as follows:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('test.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
```

I don't know why there is no space in output, the tested pdf shows like this:

```
CompetingConservationObjectivesforPredatorsandPrey:EstimatingKillerWhalePreyRequirementsforChinookSalmonRobWilliams,MartinKrkos,ErinAshe,TrevorA.Branch,SteveClark,PhilipS.HammondErichHoyt,DawnP.Noren,DavidRosen,ArlissWinshipUniversityofWashington,
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix or where to fix it?

Comment: do you expect us to be familiar with every script ever written?

Comment: Question does not follow required layout, please edit to fit requirements, question is off topic. 1. problem is unclear. 2. expected results are unclear.

Comment: Not *all* text in *all* PDFs can reliable be 'extracted'. Can you use Acrobat Reader to copy the right text?